# Activate small caps for Minion Pro

Tags: luatex, fontspec

Using the Minion Pro OTF font with TeX Live 2021, small caps do not show up:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MinionPro}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Hello, there!}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

But `otfinfo -f MinionPro-Regular.otf` says that small caps are available:

```
...
smcp    Small Capitals
...
```

Is there any way to activate them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I get small caps.

Comment: check in the log which font is actually used.

Comment: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'TU/MinionPro(1)/m/sc' undefined`

Comment: Do you have an old MinionPro file sitting somewhere in the search path? The log shows the path.

Comment: According to the log, the only OTF font loaded is `~/.fonts/Minion Pro/MinionPro-Regular.otf`. The font `MinionPro(0)` is recognised as having small caps: `'small caps'  (m/sc)`. I have to clue where `MinionPro(1)` comes from.

Comment: I also don't get small caps.  And I don't get a warning that some font shape is undefined.  Otherwise it is working fine.  Have you solved your problem?